# How to show that a monotonously decreasing positive function $f(x)$ where there exist not $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)\ge \delta$ $f(x)\to 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

Say I have a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb  R$. Say this function is a monotonously decreasing positive function, that is

$$f(x+\epsilon)\leq f(x)\\f(x)\ge 0\; \forall x$$

and $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary small, and also there exist no $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)\ge \delta$.

how could one show ${\lim _{x \to \infty }}f\left( x \right) = 0$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks, edits has been done!!

Comment: What is $\varepsilon$?

Comment: I think something is missing. Take for example $f(x)=e^{-x} + 5$, which should satisfy your assumptions. Maybe something like $\forall \varepsilon>0$ $\exists x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)\leq \varepsilon$?

Comment: @humanStampedist I said can not be lower bounded.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not notice it, because it is not stated in the body of the question.

Comment: No worries, my mistake!

Comment: But please also edit the title because as it stands, the above example renders it false.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try a proof: Let us proceed by contradiction, i.e. let us assume we have a sequence $x_n\in\mathbb{R}$ and a $C>0$, such that
$$x_n\rightarrow\infty,\ f(x_n)\geq C.$$
Since $f$ cannot be bounded away from zero, we find an $x\in\mathbb{R}$, such that
$$0 < f(x) < C.$$
Since $f$ is monotone we necessarily have for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$x_n\leq x,$$
which is a contradiction.